# Permanent redirect while reverse proxying with nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have setup an nginx reverse proxy server which proxy `blog.xxx.com` to `xxx.com/blog`. Here is my config file.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/html;
    server_name xxx.com www.xxx.com;
    
    location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        root /tmp/letsencrypt/www;
    }
    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
server {

    listen 443;
    
    server_name xxx.com;
    
    root /var/www/html;

    include /etc/nginx/snippet/ssl.conf;
    
    location /blog/ {
        proxy_pass https://blog.xxx.com;
        proxy_set_header Host blog.xxx.com;
        rewrite /blog/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_redirect off;
        expires -1;
        add_header Cache-Control no-store;
        proxy_read_timeout 90;
        proxy_connect_timeout 90;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://xxx:8090;
    }
    
}
```

It works just fine. But I need to have a permanent redirect on `blog.xxx.com` to `xxx.com/blog` as well. Once I set the redirect rule, a `too many redirects` situation happens.

Is there any way to have both reverse proxy and 301 redirect at the same time?

Comment: How is `blog.xxx.com` hosted and how much control do you have over it?

Comment: @RichardSmith it is hosted on siteground with full control over its settings...

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand correctly that the two sites mentioned are hosted in different places? If so, I would do a 303 redirect to your second page on the first page. If you don't have Nginx on the first page, you can probably do this in your blog software (or directly in HTML, PHP, etc.) To prevent endless redirection, you can rewrite them while sending them to the client:

https://serverfault.com/a/986034/304842